# Error in XMI file

Tags: java, parsing, xml-parsing, xmi, argouml

I'm trying to parse this XMI file http://pastebin.com/Ltp09cPD in java, this file has been generated with ArgoUML but I get this error:

```
"Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/SredXNY/Google%20Drive/Tesis/Ejemplos%20de%20XMI/argo.xmi; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 167; El tipo de elemento "UML:UseCase" debe ir seguido de una de estas especificaciones de atributo: ">" o "/>"."
```

in english it's something like `"the type of element "UML:UseCase" must be followed for one of this attribute especifications: ">" or "/>"`

what's wrong in the file? I cannot find something wrong

Answer (score 1):

Line #12 currently reads:

```
... isLeaf = 'false'isAbstract ...
```

Just add an extra space to make it work:

```
... isLeaf = 'false' isAbstract ...
```